# What is the complexity class of exponential parallelism?

Tags: complexity-theory, parallel-computing, quantum-computing

Consider the class of problems that can be computed when you have access to exponentially many processors working in parallel.

How does one capture that in a proper formalism? Is there some literature on it already? Would it be true that such a class would be a superset of BQP?

Comment: "exponentially many processors working in parallel" And with *unbounded* time and space requirements on each processor?

Comment: @dkaeae polynomial time and space requirements on each processor

Comment: Well Nick's Class $NC^i$ concerns polynomially many processors in parallel with shared memory, it stratifies $P$ (conjectured to reach $P$).  I would think the natural thing to generalize is non-deterministic NC. See Caussinus-MacKinzie and references form there.